# SQLite trigger with temporal condition

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, web-applications, triggers

i'm developing a HTML+PHP+JS Web Application with SQLite database that uses discount vouchers with an expiry date. So, i have the following table

```
idvoucher|cod|title|       expires      |status
```

and i want to change 'status' column when actual date reaches 'expires' column.

I've searched for sqlite triggers that can be fired with temporal conditions but found nothing. Any ideias?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: There is no such trigger. Additionally, what you're trying to do violates third normal form. Write a query that compares `expires` to the current time and have it return `"expired"` instead.

Comment: ok, i run that query when user logs in but when/where shall i run that query if i want to email a customer (that is not logged in) that one voucher is now expired or 5 days left to expire

Answer (score 0):

A query like this returns all vouchers that need to expire:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vouchers
WHERE expires >= datetime('now')
  AND status != 'expired'
```

To change them to `'expired'`, run an UPDATE statement instead.

There is no mechanism in SQLite to run this automatically; you have to check regularly from your service code.
(This is not possible with a web application that does not run when nobody opens a web page.)